# How to include pages in a JSPX and Trinidad project in run-time without breaking the JSF lifecycle?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jspx, trinidad

I am struggling to figure out a way to include dynamically determined pages in run-time in a JSPX and Trinidad project. You will have an idea when you see what I have, which is:

```
<tr:panelAccordion>

<tr:showDetailItem
    text="Test tab">
    <jsp:include page=".test.jspx" /> <!-- This part is working fine -->
</tr:showDetailItem>

<jsp:scriptlet>
    BackingTest backing = (BackingTest) session.getAttribute("backingTest");
    for (CaseTabConfigurationDTO tab : backing.getTabs()) {

        java.io.File f = new java.io.File(request.getRealPath(tab.getPagePath()));
        if (f.exists()) {
            pageContext.include(tab.getPagePath(), true);
        }
    }
</jsp:scriptlet>
</tr:panelAccordion>
```

jsp:include part is working fine, nothing is breaking the JSF lifecycle.

jsp:scriplet part is successful for including the correct pages. However, it is breaking the later actions in JSF lifecycle including still persisting backing beans of dialogs opened using useWindow="true".

In order to be make it complaint with Facelet, thus not breaking JSF lifecycle. I tried using tr:forEach, c:forEach, ui:include, ui:repeat approaches without any luck of actually including pages.

Can you share a proper solution for it? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to reconfigure your project so you can [use Facelets with Trinidad](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Facelets_with_Trinidad). After reconfiguring your project can use [Facelets](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gijtu.html) for templating. You will end up using `xhtml` instead of `jspx` though.

See also:

- [When to use <ui:include>, tag files, composite components and/or custom components?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen)
- [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)